# PHP - Most Efficient Dictionary Code

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary

I'm using the following code to pull the definition of a word from a tab-delimited file with only two columns (word, definition). Is this the most efficient code for what I'm trying to do?

```
<?php
$haystack  = file("dictionary.txt");
$needle = 'apple';

$flipped_haystack = array_flip($haystack);

foreach($haystack as $value)
    {
    $haystack = explode("\t", $value);

    if ($haystack[0] == $needle)
        {
        echo "Definition of $needle: $haystack[1]";
        $defined = "1";
        break;
        }
    }

if($defined != "1")
    {
    echo "$needle not found!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: How slow is it? Are you facing problems with it?

Comment: @RichBradshaw Currently, it isn't slow or problematic because I only have a few entries, but I will be building up to have 100,000+ entries.

Comment: Why not generate a similar size data set randomly (i.e. a row might be 'sdfkjalwerjkl   8yuoayisyfiuh2342 asdkfh kdh slfk jsfhalsdkjf' or what ever, then try your code on that – if it's slow then this is a worthwhile place to spend your time – if it's not, then problem solved! :) Using a trie is the 'right way', but 100,000 isn't a lot of data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you're doing a lot of pointless work

```
1) load the file into a per-line array
2) flip the array
3) iterate over and explode every value of the array
4) test that exploded value
```

You can't really avoid step 1, but why do you have to do all that useless "busy work" for 2&3?

e.g. if your dictionary text was set up something like this:

```
word:definition
```

then a simple:

```
$matches = preg_grep('/^$word:(.*)$/', $haystack);
```

would do the trick for you, with far less code.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working for me. Am I doing something wrong? ` <?php
 $haystack  = file("dictionary.txt");
 $needle = 'apple';

 $matches = preg_grep('/^$needle:(.*)$/', $haystack);
 if ($matches)
  {
  echo "Definition of $needle: $matches[1]";
  }
 else
  {
  echo "$needle not found!";
  }
 ?>` (I can't get the code markdown to work.)

Comment: `('/^$needle:(.*)$/'` should be `("/^$needle:(.*)$/"`. (Use backticks (`) around code.)

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. That is much more efficient than what I originally had. Thanks for helping me learn something new.

Comment: RegEx is always a last resort. It's extremely expensive.

Comment: RegEx is always a last resort. It's extremely expensive especially when using it on large amounts of text. Consider using `strpos` and `substr` related functions.

Answer (score 2):

No. Most likely a trie is more efficient and you didn't sort your dictionary and it doesn't use a binary tree or ternary tree. I guess if you need to search in a huge dictionary your method is simply too slow.

Comment: To add, it definitely depends on how large dictionary.txt is and how its organized. The current algorithm only eliminates one possibility per iteration, which makes it extremely slow.

Comment: @NicholasPickering dictionary.txt is alphabetically organized. Ultimately it will have 100,000+ entries. What would be a better method to use than what I'm currently using?

Comment: @phpdna Thanks, this is my first time hearing of trie's, but it is surely something I will be looking into to see what all can be accomplished with a trie.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this the most efficient code for what I'm trying to do?

Surely not.
To find only **one** needle you are processing **all** the entries.

> I will be building up to have 100,000+ entries.

use a database then.

Comment: Yes. A database will create and store a btree based structure and as it will be accessed by highly optimized  binary code it will be faster than any code in php.